# How to avoid using the same switch statement in different functions?

Tags: c#, optimization, delegates, switch-statement

I have an interface for a class and the functions of the interface should behave differently depending on the state (enum) of the class where i use the functions.

```
public class Test : Interface
{
    Enum state = Enum.s1;
    int test = 0
    public void fn1(int x)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case Enum.s1:
                {
                    test += x;
                    break;
                }
            ...
        }
    }
    public void fn2(int x, ref int y)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case Enum.s1:
                {
                    y += x*test;
                    break;
                }
            ...
        }
    }
    public bool fn3()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case Enum.s1:
                {
                    return DoStuff(test);
                    break;
                }
            ...
        }

    }
}
```

Is it possible to make a single evaluation and use it for all functions?

I'm new to delegates but is it maybe a good solution to just make a delegate for fn1/fn2/fn3 and fill them every time the state changes with the needed functions?

I ask because I think there is a better solution for this.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: ...move it in a new function and call that one?

Comment: Why do you need the 3 functions instead of just one, called 3 times?

Comment: Just the switch statement is the same, the content is different

Comment: Maybe a Visitor pattern with 3 visitors is appropriate. But we don't know enough about your override, you override something, but the class has no baseclass. That is important to a possible answer.

Comment: The functions are used for different tasks. Each task should check the state of the class and execute what's inside

Comment: The interface isn't made by myself. I just use the functions and know at what time the functions get called.

Comment: @RiseBasti do the methods take any parameters that you arent showing?  If they are modifying a class level variable/property than you need to show that

Comment: Also, you say you are implementing an interface... but why is the `override` keyword there?  That would indicate a `virtual` or `abstract` method in the chain but you arent indicating that here

Comment: @maccettura yes they do. i'll update that in the question. The interface is already implemented and i'm just using it with my new class.

Comment: @RiseBasti `"The interface is already implemented and i'm just using it with my new class"` -- this does not make sense to me.  You do not need the `override` keyword with interfaces, so is there a base class (abstract or not) that you arent showing?

Comment: @maccettura you are right, i just updated the question. The code got updated to an interface some time ago and i forgott the override dissapeared cause of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an interface for a class and the functions of the interface should behave differently depending on the state (enum) of the class where i use the functions.
>
> Is it possible to make a single evaluation and use it for all functions?

Yes and No.

**No**, it is not possible to solve it better with Enum and control structures. A Enum fed into a switch/case is already the least amount of work you can do in code.

**Yes**, it is possible to do it better. What you should have here is not 1 Implementation that behaves different on a Enum Value. You should have 3 different Implementations for this Interface all along

Different behavior over a bunch of functions, all referencing the same thing? That is what Overriding during inheritance is there for!

There could be only one odd case, and that is if you need to be able to *change* the Enum/Convert between states. That is not much of a problem either thanks to the ability of using one instance to initialize another.

Take a look at the `List<T>` [class constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__). One of them takes a `IEnumerable<T>` as input. All generic collections implement that interface, and even arrays are implicitly coverted into one (happens every time you use foreach loop, in fact). So they can all use each other as initializers. It also has a `ToArray()` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray).

I could have sworn some Stream Classes could take other Streams as Constructor Argument. A simple way to wrap streams up in one another. But can not find it. In any case most take `Byte[]` as C-tor argument. And they all can be expressed/implicitly converted into `Byte[]`. Oddly that behavior is not even defined in the abstract base class. It is just something most inheritors do.

Edit: Also if you still need the Enum value for other code: A readonly property. Unlike normal fields they can be added to Interfaces. And each implementation could return a different, hardcoded value.